# How to unblock service discovery for IPv4 via Avahi?

Tags: firewall, avahi

On a Debian 6.0.6 system (squeeze) I am having trouble resolving a host using Avahi and IPv4.  Here is a sample output:

```
: nr@homedog 10102 ; avahi-browse -a
+   eth0 IPv6 yorkie [00:1f:3b:d8:67:1d]     Workstation          local
+   eth0 IPv6 homedog [bc:5f:f4:5a:b1:73]    Workstation          local
+   eth0 IPv4 homedog [bc:5f:f4:5a:b1:73]    Workstation          local
```

Notice that `homedog`, the local machine, is visible both on IPv6 and IPv4.  But `yorkie`, the remote machine, is visible only on IPv4.  And `avahi-resolve-host-name -4 yorkie.local` hangs with no result.

**EDIT**: The situation is symmetric: `yorkie` sees itself on IPv4 and IPv6, but it sees `homedog` on IPv6 only.

On `yorkie`, the output from `iptables -vnL` is

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 109K packets, 98M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source   destination     

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source   destination  

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 108K packets, 94M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source   destination
```

(To make the display fit StackExchange without wrapping, I have taken a couple of liberties with horizontal space.)  The display on `homedog` is identical except for the numbers: for all three, it displays 0 packets and 0 bytes.
(I have no clue how to interpret these outputs, but it may be informative that `yorkie`'s current uptime is 41 days and `homedog`'s current uptime is 6 hours.)

I found a closed ticket at http://avahi.org/ticket/297, which suggests that the problem is some sort of firewall configuration.  I am a complete novice in this area, and through web search I have been unable to inform myself about how to use the `iptables` command to diagnose or repair the problem.  I found another ticket as [Debian bug 547974](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=547974), but this bug was closed without explaining how to fix the problem.

The hypothesis is that somehow the service-discovery packet is being blocked—I don't know on which machine.  Can anyone say how to discover **which machine is blocking the packet** and **how to reconfigure it** so Avahi discovers the IPv4 address?

Comment: `iptables -vnL` is a good start at dumping everything in there for IPv4 rules (`ip6tables` is used for IPv6 rules).  If `homedog` can see itself on both IPv4 and IPv6, the obvious next step to see where it's broken is to see if `yorkie` can see itself on both IPv4 and IPv6

Comment: @DerfK thanks for helping me improve my question.  Visibility is symmetric, but `iptables` shows many more bytes and packets on yorkie.

Comment: Do you actually need IPv4 here?

Comment: @Michael, I don't know.  I have no particular brief for one or the other, but I can't figure out how to get `ssh` to work with IPv6.  I have my `/etc/nsswitch.conf` configured to work with mdns4, but doing `ssh -6 yorkie.local` results in a failure to resolve the hostname.

Comment: If avahi is actually running, `ssh yorkie` _should_ be sufficient.

Comment: @Michael, `avahi-resolve-host-name` finds `yorkie.local` (with an IPv6 address) but not `yorkie`.  My `/etc/resolv.conf` could be at fault.

Answer (score 0):

This one isn't still fully diagnosed, but it was a combination of two problems:

- On host `yorkie`, some unknown daemon keeps installing `iptables` rules.  I remove the rules, but eventually they reappear.
- The more pernicious part: `yorkie` is connected wirelessly, and **my Verizon ActionTec router was blocking mDNS packets.

With *both* problems resolved, `avahi-browse -a` works as expected.